# How to show only nearest i element?

Tags: jquery

I have hidden icon and link (a) elements. I want that when you hover on a only nearest I show.

Now every time you hover one a all icons show hide.

I already tried:

```
$(this).closest(".fa.fa-arrow-right").show();
```

but it doesn't work.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('i.fa.fa-arrow-right').hide();

    $('.mega-menu a').bind('mouseover', function() {
        $('i.fa.fa-arrow-right').show();
    }); 

    $('.mega-menu a').bind('mouseleave', function() {
        $('i.fa.fa-arrow-right').hide();
    });  
});
```

Here is important part of html:

```
<div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_inner vc_row-fluid">
    <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-4">
        <div class="vc_column-inner ">
            <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
                    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                        <p><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" style="display: none;"></i><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-4">
        <div class="vc_column-inner "><div class="wpb_wrapper">
            <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
                <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                    <p><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" style="display: none;"></i><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-4">
    <div class="vc_column-inner "><div class="wpb_wrapper">
        <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
            <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                <p><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" style="display: none;"></i><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($)
{
   $('i.fa.fa-arrow-right').hide();

   $('.mega-menu a').bind('mouseover', function ()
   {
       $(this).siblings('i.fa.fa-arrow-right').show();
   }); 

   $('.mega-menu a').bind('mouseleave', function ()
   {
       $('i.fa.fa-arrow-right').hide();
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `$(this).prev('i')` it should work.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, i was looking for the class mega... i cant find it... but you can do as followed:

.find(".fu") -> find in children of the element

.siblings(".fu") -> find... well... the siblings

.parents(".fu") -> find in parents of the Element

i'm not sure where your js is targeted so i hope this is a help.

Answer (score 0):

Check below code. I hope it gives your expected output.

```js
// For mouseover
$('a').mouseover(function() {
  $(this).prev('i').show();

});

// For mouseout
$('a').mouseout(function() {
  $(this).prev('i').hide();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css' integrity='sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ' crossorigin='anonymous'>
<div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_inner vc_row-fluid">
  <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-4">
    <div class="vc_column-inner ">
      <div class="wpb_wrapper">
        <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
          <div class="wpb_wrapper">
            <p><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" style="display: none;"></i><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></p>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-4">
    <div class="vc_column-inner ">
      <div class="wpb_wrapper">
        <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
          <div class="wpb_wrapper">
            <p><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" style="display: none;"></i><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></p>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-4">
    <div class="vc_column-inner ">
      <div class="wpb_wrapper">
        <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
          <div class="wpb_wrapper">
            <p><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" style="display: none;"></i><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></p>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```